# React-Virtualized Autosizer Height Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

My parent div is 100% of the parent (which is in turn 100%, etc), and one of the parents has some padding.

AutoSizer is not respecting the padding at the bottom, and also the list stops scrolling before all the items have been seen.

```
<AutoSizer>
  {({ width, height }) => (
    <List
      height={height}
      rowCount={data.length}
      rowHeight={53}
      rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer.bind(this, data)}
      width={width}
    />
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

Bottom padding on grandparent is ignored:
[image: Bottom padding on grandparent container not respected]

Rows stop rendering early:
[image: Rows stop rendering early]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second problem you've mentioned indicates that you are not accepting/applying the `style` property passed to the row renderer. See [here](https://bvaughn.github.io/connect-tech-2016/#/32/1) for an illustration.

> AutoSizer is not respecting the padding at the bottom

As for this, it sounds like your CSS isn't setup quite right. Try setting the padding on anything *except* the immediate parent of `AutoSizer`. :)